# Reading .csv file into list of tuples suggestions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm having some trouble getting this function to return exactly the results I need.

The function takes a .csv file as input ("," delimiter), and is supposed to store various columns into objects, and store those into a list of tuples.

These are the columns of interest:

```
year = int(line[2])
month = int(line[3])
magnitude = float(line[9])
location = line[19]
latitude = float(line[20])
longitude = float(line[21])
deaths = int(line[23])
missing = int(line[25])
injuries = int(line[27])
damages = float(line[29])
```

There's also the following conditions:

> If the number of deaths, missing, injured, and damages columns are
> empty, replace it with a zero. If any other numerical data cannot be
> made into an int or float, skip that entire line of data

So I botched together a function that "works", however it has some issues.

1. It doesn't skip the entire row if one of the values cannot be converted to int() or float()
2. I don't believe it's sorting into the required order (which is worded as "sort the list of tuples using the default settings"
3. Mine isn't returning list/tuple items as integers, they're strings i believe.

I'm still learning, so please keep that in mind.

Here's what I have:

```
def read_file(fp):
    next(fp, None)
    masterList = []
    tup = ()

for line in csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True):
    year = line[2]
    month = line[3]
    magnitude = line[9]
    location = line[19]
    latitude = line[20]
    longitude = line[21]
    deaths = line[23]
    missing = line[25]
    injured = line[27]
    damages = line[29]

    try:
        year = int(year)
        month = int(month)
        magnitude = float(magnitude)
        latitude = float(latitude)
        longitude = float(longitude)

        if deaths.isdigit() == True:
            if len(deaths) < 1:
                deaths = int('0')
        else:
            next(fp)
        if missing.isdigit() == True:
            if len(missing) < 1:
                missing = int('0')
        else:
            next(fp)
        if injured.isdigit() == True:
            if len(injured) < 1:
                injured = int('0')
        else:
            next(fp)
        if damages.isdigit() == True:
            if len(damages) < 1:
                damages = float('0.0')
        else:
            next(fp)
    except:
        next(fp)

    tup = (year,month,magnitude,location,latitude,longitude,deaths,missing,injured,damages)
    masterList.append(tup)

masterList = sorted(masterList)
print(masterList)
return masterList
```

would somebody please throw me some pointers?

Example CSV:

```
I_D,FLAG_TSUNAMI,YEAR,MONTH,DAY,HOUR,MINUTE,SECOND,FOCAL_DEPTH,EQ_PRIMARY,EQ_MAG_MW,EQ_MAG_MS,EQ_MAG_MB,EQ_MAG_ML,EQ_MAG_MFA,EQ_MAG_UNK,INTENSITY,COUNTRY,STATE,LOCATION_NAME,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,REGION_CODE,DEATHS,DEATHS_DESCRIPTION,MISSING,MISSING_DESCRIPTION,INJURIES,INJURIES_DESCRIPTION,DAMAGE_MILLIONS_DOLLARS,DAMAGE_DESCRIPTION,HOUSES_DESTROYED,HOUSES_DESTROYED_DESCRIPTION,HOUSES_DAMAGED,HOUSES_DAMAGED_DESCRIPTION,TOTAL_DEATHS,TOTAL_DEATHS_DESCRIPTION,TOTAL_MISSING,TOTAL_MISSING_DESCRIPTION,TOTAL_INJURIES,TOTAL_INJURIES_DESCRIPTION,TOTAL_DAMAGE_MILLIONS_DOLLARS,TOTAL_DAMAGE_DESCRIPTION,TOTAL_HOUSES_DESTROYED,TOTAL_HOUSES_DESTROYED_DESCRIPTION,TOTAL_HOUSES_DAMAGED,TOTAL_HOUSES_DAMAGED_DESCRIPTION
10467,Tsu,2020,1,7,8,24,26,10,6.4,6.4,,,,,,8,USA TERRITORY,PR,PUERTO RICO:  PONCE,SAN JUAN,17.916,-66.813,90,4,1,,,,1,,4,300,3,1390,4,4,1,,,,1,,4,300,3,1390,4
10474,,2020,1,19,13,27,56,6,6,6,,,,,,,CHINA,,CHINA:  XINJIANG PROVINCE,39.831,77.106,40,1,1,,,2,1,,3,,,,4,1,1,,,2,1,,3,,,,4
10475,,2020,1,24,17,55,14,12,6.7,6.7,,,,,,,TURKEY,,TURKEY:  ELAZIG AND MALATYA PROVINCES,38.39,39.081,140,41,1,,,1600,4,,4,76,2,,4,41,1,,,1600,4,,4,76,2,,4
10476,Tsu,2020,1,28,19,10,25,10,7.7,7.7,,,,,,,CUBA,,CUBA: GRANMA;  CAYMAN IS;  JAMAICA,19.44,-78.755,90,,,,,,,,2,1,1,,3,,,,,,,,2,1,1,,3
10480,,2020,2,23,16,0,31,10,6,6,,,,,,,IRAN,,TURKEY: VAN;  IRAN,38.482,44.367,140,10,1,,,60,2,,2,255,3,600,3,10,1,,,60,2,,2,255,3,600,3
10483,,2020,3,10,10,18,6,23,5,,,5,,,,8,INDONESIA,,INDONESIA:  JAVA:  SUKABUMI, BOGOR,-6.808,106.676,60,,,,,4,1,,2,,,1137,4,,,,,4,1,,2,,,1137,4
10485,,2020,3,18,13,9,31,12,5.7,5.7,,,,,,6,USA,UT,USA: UTAH,40.751,-112.078,150,,,,,,,48.5,4,,,,3,,,,,,,48.5,4,,,,3
10486,,2020,3,22,5,24,3,10,5.4,5.4,,,,,,8,CROATIA,,BALKANS NW:  CROATIA:  ZAGREB,45.897,15.966,130,1,1,,,27,1,6000,4,6305,4,20000,4,1,1,,,27,1,6000,4,6305,4,20000,4
10487,Tsu,2020,3,25,2,49,21,57,7.5,7.5,,,,,,6,RUSSIA,,RUSSIA:  KURIL ISLANDS,48.986,157.693,50,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10488,,2020,4,1,12,23,27,10,5.3,5.3,,,,,,,CHINA,,CHINA:  QINGHAI PROVINCE,33.124,98.916,30,,,,,,,11.28,3,,,790,3,,,,,,,11.28,3,,,790,3
10490,Tsu,2020,5,2,12,51,6,17,6.6,6.6,,,,,,7,GREECE,,GREECE:  CRETE,34.205,25.712,130,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10491,,2020,5,7,20,18,22,10,4.6,,,4.6,,,,,IRAN,,IRAN:  TEHRAN, DAMAVAND,35.725,52.044,140,2,1,,,22,1,,,,,,,2,1,,,22,1,,,,,,
10494,,2020,5,18,13,48,3,10,5.2,5.2,,,,,,,CHINA,,CHINA:   YUNNAN PROVINCE:  QIAOJIA,27.296,103.281,30,4,1,,,24,1,,2,,1,,,4,1,,,24,1,,2,,1,,
10501,Tsu,2020,5,29,5,30,,,,,,,,,,,INDONESIA,,INDONESIA:  JAVA:  IJEN,-8.058,114.242,60,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,,,,,,,,,
10502,,2020,6,4,8,49,39,107,6.4,6.4,,,,,,4,INDONESIA,,INDONESIA: NORTH MALUKU: MOROTAI,2.923,128.248,170,,,,,,,,2,14,1,298,3,,,,,,,,2,14,1,298,3
10503,,2020,6,7,5,27,22,57,4.5,,,4.5,,,,,PERU,,PERU:  COAST:  CHIMBOTE,-9.634,-78.591,160,1,1,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,,,,,,,,,
10504,,2020,6,14,14,24,29,10,5.9,5.9,,,,,,,TURKEY,,TURKEY:  BINGOL,39.421,40.697,140,1,1,,,17,1,,2,,,,1,1,1,,,17,1,,2,,,,1
10505,Tsu,2020,6,18,12,49,53,10,7.4,7.4,,,,,,,NEW ZEALAND,,KERMADEC ISLANDS:  S OF, RAOUL,-33.294,-177.838,170,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10506,Tsu,2020,6,23,15,29,5,26,7.4,7.4,,,,,,,MEXICO,,MEXICO: OAXACA,16.029,-95.901,150,10,1,,,,1,,4,,,8123,4,10,1,,,,1,,4,,,8123,4
10507,,2020,6,25,10,3,31,10,5.4,5.4,,,,,,,TURKEY,,TURKEY:  VAN,38.558,44.023,140,,,,,5,1,,2,,,90,2,,,,,5,1,,2,,,90,2
10510,,2020,7,17,2,50,23,80,7,7,,,,,,,PAPUA NEW GUINEA,,PAPUA NEW GUINEA:  MOROBE, ORO,-7.843,147.766,170,,,,,1,1,,1,,,12,1,1,1,,,1,1,,1,,,12,1
10509,Tsu,2020,7,22,6,12,44,28,7.8,7.8,,,,,,8,USA,AK,USA: ALASKA,55.03,-158.522,150,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
10511,,2020,7,27,5,14,51,10,4.8,,,4.8,,,,,VIETNAM,,VIETNAM: SON LA PROVINCE,20.872,104.541,30,,,,,,,,2,,,,3,,,,,,,,2,,,,3
10514,,2020,8,9,12,7,37,8,5.1,5.1,,,,,,,USA,NC,USA: NORTH CAROLINA:  SPARTA,36.476,-81.094,150,,,,,,,,2,60,2,465,3,,,,,,,,2,60,2,465,3
10515,,2020,8,18,0,3,48,10,6.6,6.6,,,,,,7,PHILIPPINES,,PHILIPPINES:  MASBATE,12.021,124.123,170,1,1,,,48,1,,2,14,1,2,1,1,1,,,48,1,,2,14,1,2,1
```

Test input:

```
[(2020, 1, 6.0, 'CHINA:  XINJIANG PROVINCE', 39.831, 77.106, 1, 0, 2, 0), (2020, 1, 6.7, 'TURKEY:  ELAZIG AND MALATYA PROVINCES', 38.39, 39.081, 41, 0, 1600, 0), (2020, 1, 7.7, 'CUBA: GRANMA;  CAYMAN IS;  JAMAICA', 19.44, -78.755, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 2, 6.0, 'TURKEY: VAN;  IRAN', 38.482, 44.367, 10, 0, 60, 0), (2020, 3, 5.4, 'BALKANS NW:  CROATIA:  ZAGREB', 45.897, 15.966, 1, 0, 27, 6000.0), (2020, 3, 5.7, 'USA: UTAH', 40.751, -112.078, 0, 0, 0, 48.5), (2020, 3, 7.5, 'RUSSIA:  KURIL ISLANDS', 48.986, 157.693, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 4, 5.3, 'CHINA:  QINGHAI PROVINCE', 33.124, 98.916, 0, 0, 0, 11.28), (2020, 5, 5.2, 'CHINA:   YUNNAN PROVINCE:  QIAOJIA', 27.296, 103.281, 4, 0, 24, 0), (2020, 5, 6.6, 'GREECE:  CRETE', 34.205, 25.712, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 6, 4.5, 'PERU:  COAST:  CHIMBOTE', -9.634, -78.591, 1, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 6, 5.4, 'TURKEY:  VAN', 38.558, 44.023, 0, 0, 5, 0), (2020, 6, 5.9, 'TURKEY:  BINGOL', 39.421, 40.697, 1, 0, 17, 0), (2020, 6, 6.4, 'INDONESIA: NORTH MALUKU: MOROTAI', 2.923, 128.248, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 6, 7.4, 'MEXICO: OAXACA', 16.029, -95.901, 10, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 7, 4.8, 'VIETNAM: SON LA PROVINCE', 20.872, 104.541, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 7, 7.8, 'USA: ALASKA', 55.03, -158.522, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 8, 5.1, 'USA: NORTH CAROLINA:  SPARTA', 36.476, -81.094, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 8, 6.6, 'PHILIPPINES:  MASBATE', 12.021, 124.123, 1, 0, 48, 0)]
```

Expected output:

```
[(2020, 1, 6.0, 'CHINA:  XINJIANG PROVINCE', 39.831, 77.106, 1, 0, 2, 0), (2020, 1, 6.7, 'TURKEY:  ELAZIG AND MALATYA PROVINCES', 38.39, 39.081, 41, 0, 1600, 0), (2020, 1, 7.7, 'CUBA: GRANMA;  CAYMAN IS;  JAMAICA', 19.44, -78.755, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 2, 6.0, 'TURKEY: VAN;  IRAN', 38.482, 44.367, 10, 0, 60, 0), (2020, 3, 5.4, 'BALKANS NW:  CROATIA:  ZAGREB', 45.897, 15.966, 1, 0, 27, 6000.0), (2020, 3, 5.7, 'USA: UTAH', 40.751, -112.078, 0, 0, 0, 48.5), (2020, 3, 7.5, 'RUSSIA:  KURIL ISLANDS', 48.986, 157.693, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 4, 5.3, 'CHINA:  QINGHAI PROVINCE', 33.124, 98.916, 0, 0, 0, 11.28), (2020, 5, 5.2, 'CHINA:   YUNNAN PROVINCE:  QIAOJIA', 27.296, 103.281, 4, 0, 24, 0), (2020, 5, 6.6, 'GREECE:  CRETE', 34.205, 25.712, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 6, 4.5, 'PERU:  COAST:  CHIMBOTE', -9.634, -78.591, 1, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 6, 5.4, 'TURKEY:  VAN', 38.558, 44.023, 0, 0, 5, 0), (2020, 6, 5.9, 'TURKEY:  BINGOL', 39.421, 40.697, 1, 0, 17, 0), (2020, 6, 6.4, 'INDONESIA: NORTH MALUKU: MOROTAI', 2.923, 128.248, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 6, 7.4, 'MEXICO: OAXACA', 16.029, -95.901, 10, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 7, 4.8, 'VIETNAM: SON LA PROVINCE', 20.872, 104.541, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 7, 7.8, 'USA: ALASKA', 55.03, -158.522, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 8, 5.1, 'USA: NORTH CAROLINA:  SPARTA', 36.476, -81.094, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2020, 8, 6.6, 'PHILIPPINES:  MASBATE', 12.021, 124.123, 1, 0, 48, 0)]
```

My output:

```
[('2020', '1', '6.4', 'PUERTO RICO:  PONCE', 'SAN JUAN', '17.916', '90', '1', '', '1'), ('2020', '1', '6.7', 'TURKEY:  ELAZIG AND MALATYA PROVINCES', '38.39', '39.081', '41', 0, '1600', 0.0), ('2020', '1', '7.7', 'CUBA: GRANMA;  CAYMAN IS;  JAMAICA', '19.44', '-78.755', 0, 0, 0, 0.0), ('2020', '2', '6', 'TURKEY: VAN;  IRAN', '38.482', '44.367', '10', 0, '60', 0.0), ('2020', '3', '5', 'INDONESIA:  JAVA:  SUKABUMI', 'BOGOR', '-6.808', '60', '', '', '1'), ('2020', '3', '5.4', 'BALKANS NW:  CROATIA:  ZAGREB', '45.897', '15.966', '1', 0, '27', '6000'), ('2020', '3', '7.5', 'RUSSIA:  KURIL ISLANDS', '48.986', '157.693', 0, 0, 0, 0.0), ('2020', '4', '5.3', 'CHINA:  QINGHAI PROVINCE', '33.124', '98.916', 0, 0, 0, '11.28'), ('2020', '5', '', 'INDONESIA:  JAVA:  IJEN', '-8.058', '114.242', '', '', '', ''), ('2020', '5', '4.6', 'IRAN:  TEHRAN', 'DAMAVAND', '35.725', '140', '1', '', '1'), ('2020', '5', '6.6', 'GREECE:  CRETE', '34.205', '25.712', 0, 0, 0, 0.0), ('2020', '6', '4.5', 'PERU:  COAST:  CHIMBOTE', '-9.634', '-78.591', '1', 0, 0, 0.0), ('2020', '6', '5.4', 'TURKEY:  VAN', '38.558', '44.023', 0, 0, '5', 0.0), ('2020', '6', '5.9', 'TURKEY:  BINGOL', '39.421', '40.697', '1', 0, '17', 0.0), ('2020', '6', '7.4', 'KERMADEC ISLANDS:  S OF', 'RAOUL', '-33.294', '170', '', '', ''), ('2020', '7', '4.8', 'VIETNAM: SON LA PROVINCE', '20.872', '104.541', 0, 0, 0, 0.0), ('2020', '7', '7', 'PAPUA NEW GUINEA:  MOROBE', 'ORO', '-7.843', '170', '', '', '1'), ('2020', '8', '5.1', 'USA: NORTH CAROLINA:  SPARTA', '36.476', '-81.094', 0, 0, 0, 0.0), ('2020', '8', '6.6', 'PHILIPPINES:  MASBATE', '12.021', '124.123', '1', 0, '48', 0.0)]
```

Comment: Can you post sample CSV with expected output please?

Comment: @Rakesh, done!!